# MKMapView region property returning bad struct

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit, cllocation

I'm working with MKMapKit and setting the region to be a full size United States and it's displaying as expected.  However when inspecting the `self.mapView.region` property I'm getting some weird results that are affecting my calculations later in the program.

Here is how I'm setting up the map view:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    MKCoordinateRegion usa = MKCoordinateRegionMake(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(39.4, -91.5), MKCoordinateSpanMake(40, 40));
    self.mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:self.mapView];
    self.mapView.region = usa;
    self.mapView.delegate = self;
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    [self.mapView.userLocation addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"location" options:0 context:nil];
}
```

This is the USA `MKCoordinateRegion`, looks fine and works:

```
(lldb) p usa
(MKCoordinateRegion) $0 = {
  (CLLocationCoordinate2D) center = {
    (CLLocationDegrees) latitude = 39.4
    (CLLocationDegrees) longitude = -91.5
  }
  (MKCoordinateSpan) span = {
    (CLLocationDegrees) latitudeDelta = 40
    (CLLocationDegrees) longitudeDelta = 40
  }
}
```

Then I set the region `self.mapView.region = usa;` and break after it, this is now the output of the `self.mapView.region`.

```
(lldb) p [self.mapView region]
(MKCoordinateRegion) $1 = {
  (CLLocationCoordinate2D) center = {
    (CLLocationDegrees) latitude = 39.4
    (CLLocationDegrees) longitude = 39.4
    (CLLocationDegrees) latitudeDelta = 39.4
    (CLLocationDegrees) longitudeDelta = -91.5
  }
  (MKCoordinateSpan) span = {
    (CLLocationDegrees) latitude = 66.4999527377778
    (CLLocationDegrees) longitude = 66.4999527377778
    (CLLocationDegrees) latitudeDelta = 66.4999527377778
    (CLLocationDegrees) longitudeDelta = 67.4999957172512
  }
  (CLLocationCoordinate2D) center = {}
}
```

So the problem is the center struct is wrong, the longitude is off and `CLLocationCoordinate2D` shouldn't even have delta fields, it looks like a `MKCoordinateSpan`.

CLLocationCoordinate2D definition:

`typedef struct {
    CLLocationDegrees latitude;
    CLLocationDegrees longitude;
} CLLocationCoordinate2D;`

So any idea where I'm going wrong?  Am I missing something blazingly obvious?  If this is the wrong way to do it, how can I get the true data to do some calculations later in the app?

Using xcode 4.6.1 and iOS 6.1 simulator.

Comment: What language are you using? There are no commas or semi-colons anywhere. It looks pretty strange to me.

Comment: Sorry it's objective-c and the other output are structs outputted by the lldb debugger in xcode.

Comment: Ah, I missed that it was output and thought it was your input to set usa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is just an lldv bug or an error in my lldb usage.  If I NSLog the lat/lon everything is fine.